# How to use absolute or fixed dynamic positioning for UI widget

Tags: css, positioning

I am about to author this client-side widget slider in javascript.

As users answer questions, the slider will increment.

I'm ok with making the slider background grow and shrink, but what I'm not really sure about is have the "65%" indicator "stick" to the end of the blue-coloured div, and automagically move as the slider background grows and shrinks.

Since this is javascript, i'm cool with setting the indicator's absolute position dynamically. OK, I havent really tried anything yet, because I'm guessing there are a number of ways to achieve this, so wanted to get some opinions. I'm even contemplating using qTip...but would be great to see this with css as a floating box anchored to another box

I'm imagining changing the width of two side-by-side divs (the completed vs incompleted), and have the indicator absolutely positioned relative to its container, so that it moves as the widths changes.

Possible?

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

**Working example** (thanks to Philip's answer)

http://jsfiddle.net/HP7V9/

Comment: +1 for using the word "automagically"

Comment: heres a better [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HP7V9/2/)..keep in mind that there will be the little arrow lookin thing on the bottom of the percent box, so the fact that it's raised up is actually correct

Comment: -1 for "I havent really tried anything yet" ... This completely defeats the purpose of SO. You can't expect the good people of SO do just your work for you.

Comment: As asked (even though it received a great answer) this is just too open ended for SO. If you'd like to edit your question and narrow it down, I'm happy to evaluate it again.

Comment: @besluitloos - As a warning to both you and BobTodd, please stop going after each other with your comments, votes, and flags. Getting into a protracted argument helps no one, so I suggest you just leave each other alone.

Comment: Sure thing Brad. Is there a way to block people like this somehow? + can you un-downvote the answers he has wrongfully downvoted?

Comment: @BradLarson: where can i report the continued misuse of SO, even after your warning?

Comment: @besluitloos - The votes should be nullified when the anti-serial voting script runs tonight. If you feel that a problem is persisting after that point, flag us and we'll look into it. Again, I recommend leaving each other alone, because nothing constructive can come out of continuing to argue.

Comment: @BradLarson Ok, thanks for your prompt reply and I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @besluitloos - I wouldn't be so hasty. This should have been caught, and looks like a bug in the system. I'll have these be removed manually, and I have contacted the developers about this. This user hasn't persisted with this since I warned both of you, so the point has been made. Finally, please don't insult people, because that won't help things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably just use jQuery to anchor it to the right of the loaded div and at the halfway point of the of the height of it.

So lets say we have this DOM:

Then, assuming you have the logic to resize the bar already, this jQuery would do the trick:

```
$("#loaded").resize(function(){
    var loadedDiv = $("#loaded");
    var loadedPosition = loadedDiv.position();
    var percentXPos = loadedPosition.left + loadedDiv.width() - $("#percent").width()/2;
    var percentYPos = loadedPosition.top + loadedDiv.height() / 2 - loadedDiv.height() / 2;

    $("#percent").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: percentYPos.toString() + "px",
        left: percentXPos.toString() + "px"
    });
});
```

Also, I don't think there's any reason to have a div for the not loaded part. You should make a div for the whole bar and give it a black background, then give the loaded div a higher z-index and different background color.

Keep in mind it may need minor tweaks depending on the margin, padding, etc of the elements.

Comment: awesome. can't believe this is working so fast, check my edit, with full working example. you've not quite nailed the centering of the indicator, but i'll let you off :)

Comment: @BobTodd i think my edit should take care of that :)